# Mark a Wordpress Post With A Language Flag?

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't know if it's possible, I want to mark a wordpress post depending on the language.

I write in German and English, so I thought about flagging the post by adding a img/flag below the headline of the post.

Sadly, I don't know enough php to do that. I'll give you an idea below, maybe you can help me write the proper code:

```
<?php

  if (language_attribute('en'))
  {
    (img/en.jpg)
  }
  else 
  {
    (img/de.jpg)
  }

?>
```

Comment: What's language_attribute? Custom function?